# Simultaneously deploy artifact to Maven Central and internal Nexus

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a project which deploys to Maven Central via OSSRH using the Maven `release` and `nexus-staging-maven` plugins using the directions from  http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html and http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-maven.html .

This works fine, but it often takes several hours for the artifact to be visible on Maven Central.  Often we would like to make use of the deployed artifact immediately, so we end up deploying it from our local repositories to our internal Nexus server using `deploy:deploy-file` . This works but it is inelegant and easy to forget to do.  Is there any way to make Maven deploy to an internal Nexus as well as Maven Central as part of the release process?

**Note:** This question is similar to, but not quite the same as, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019682/promote-artifact-from-internal-nexus-repository-to-maven-central

Comment: It's six years later, and I'm facing this same exact issue.  If I find a solution elsewhere, I'll link it here.

Comment: I've found a solution, and provided an answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70207242/7121505

Answer (score 2):

Add an additional execution to the `maven-deploy-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven.deploy.plugin.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>nexus-deploy</id>
      <phase>deploy</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <altDeploymentRepository>yourNexusRepo</altDeploymentRepository>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The yourNexusRepo value will look something like this:

```
releases::default::https://nexus.host.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases
```

You should be able to get the exact URL from Nexus.  The part before the first :: is the repository ID.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this and it did not work - it deployed only to Maven Central and did not attempt to deploy to my local Nexus.  I suspect this is due to how the release plugin does the deployment.

Comment: We use this configuration to deploy to two distinct release repositories within the same Nexus instance, so I know it works for some cases.  Might be interesting to look at debug output to make sure both executions are actually running, or to otherwise see what's going on.  We don't use the nexus staging plugin so that's one difference.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this problem by no longer using `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` as an extension.  This is described at https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/staging-releases/configuring-your-project-for-deployment :

> If more control is desired over when the plugins deploy goal is
> activated or if Maven 2 is used, you have to explicitly deactivate the
> Maven Deploy plugin and replace the Maven Deploy plugin invocation
> with the Nexus Staging Maven plugin...

In our case, we disabled the `default-deploy` execution by setting `<phase>none</phase>`.  Our full solution is available at https://github.com/newmediaworks/nmw-oss-parent/commit/a7377a158feded473cb2f1618449e34173c22252 which includes an additional execution of `maven-deploy-plugin` in the `jenkins-deploy` profile.

The key takeaway follows, which so far seems to behave as if extension were enabled, but does not interfere with additional `maven-deploy-plugin` executions:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId><artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <!--
        Not using as extension, since it blocks maven-deploy-plugin in the jenkins-deploy profile:
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        -->
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <!-- Manually added since nexus-staging-maven-plugin is not used as extension -->
                <id>default-deploy</id><phase>deploy</phase><goals><goal>deploy</goal></goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <!-- Manually disabled since nexus-staging-maven-plugin is not used as extension -->
                <id>default-deploy</id><phase>none</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```